# Lua: specify file name with variables

Tags: lua

I'd like to specify a filename based on a different id number. How can I set different a file name according to a different id value?

```
id = args.bdp_id
filename = "./temp/vtx_vel%d.dat", id
print (filename)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```
filename ="./temp/vtx_vel"..id..".dat"
```

Answer (score 3):

See [string.format](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-string.format) if you want to use sprintf style substitutions:

```
filename = string.format("./temp/vtx_vel%d.dat", id)
```